# Weird THotkey Behavior - It wont allow the same hotkey consecutively

Tags: delphi, behavior, hotkeys

Is it normal behavior for a THotkey to not allow the same hotkey twice?

Here is what I mean.

Say I set the hotkey to Ctrl+Shift+X. I then do something else, and come back to change it. While I am holding down Ctrl and Shift, I realize I dont want to change the hotkey anyway, so I press X while holding Ctrl+Shift. Now the THotkey rejects it. I let go of all the keys, and try the same combination again. It still wont let me **assign that key**. Even if I click somewhere else on my form, and go back and try the same combination, it wont let me!

Why is that? How can I prevent that?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't happen when I try it (Delphi 2009, Windows 7). Notice that the `THotkey` is a wrapper for a standard Windows control, that is, the control isn't written in Delphi. It is not even a modified (in Delphi) standard edit control; rather, the ['hot key control'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775233(VS.85).aspx) is a part of the Microsoft Windows operating system. Therefore, its behaviour depends not on Delphi version [unless there are issues with the VCL wrapping part of it], but possibly on the Windows version. Just tried it: It works in Windows 95 with Delphi 4, too.

Comment: @Andreas - I am running Windows 7, could that be the issue?

Comment: (1) Your app needs to have the focus for your hotkey to fire in the app. (2) Your handler has run into a loop/exit condition that makes it not to execute the main part of your handler. Please paste the code for your key-handler in the question.

Comment: @Johan, this isn't a question of *firing* the hotkey at run time. This is a question of *setting* the property at design time.

Comment: @Johan - it has nothing to do with firing actions when the hotkey is pressed - its about the fact that the hotkey control itself is behaving weird.

Comment: @Rob - and I need to refresh my browser more often. :P

Comment: @Rob -  this is also at Runtime!

Comment: What does "do something else" entail? What do you do with the value of the THotKey control? For instance, do you *register* it with the OS so you can receive notifications when the user presses that combination?

Comment: @Rob - "Do something else", means whenever the Exit event triggers on the THotkey. :) I use THotkeyManager.AddHotKey(); to register it as a system-wide hotkey. **That** works perfectly.

Comment: @Jeff: And then you answered your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your THotKey control loses focus, you say you register the hotkey system-wide. When you re-enter the THotKey control, the original value is still registered, so when you press that key combination, the OS intercepts it because it's a registered key combination. The THotKey control never sees it.

You need to unregister the hotkey while the THotKey control has focus.

Comment: Done! Works perfectly, why didnt I think of that? :P Thanks man!